# Set of matrices is subring of $2 \times 2 $ real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Show the set $M = \{(\begin{smallmatrix} x&y\\ -y&x \end{smallmatrix}):  \text{where } x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$

is a subring of the $2\times2$ real matrices.

proof: Let $(\begin{smallmatrix} x_1&y_1\\ -y_1&x_1 \end{smallmatrix})$, $(\begin{smallmatrix} x_2&y_2\\ -y_2&x_2 \end{smallmatrix})$ be in $M$.

Then $M$ is not empty since  $(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 &0\\ 0&0 \end{smallmatrix})$.

And $(\begin{smallmatrix} x&y\\ -y&x \end{smallmatrix}) +(\begin{smallmatrix} -x&-y\\ y&-x \end{smallmatrix}) =  (\begin{smallmatrix} 0 &0\\ 0&0 \end{smallmatrix})$

And 
if $(\begin{smallmatrix} x_1&y_1\\ -y_1&x_1 \end{smallmatrix})$+ $(\begin{smallmatrix} x_2&y_2\\ -y_2&x_2 \end{smallmatrix})$ =
$(\begin{smallmatrix} x_1 + x_2&y_1 + y_2\\ -(y_1 + y_2)&(x_1 + x_2) \end{smallmatrix})\in M$.

however, when I performed the multiplication, I dont' seem to get a similar element, so that it is in the set $M$.

Can someone please help? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the multiplication calculation:

$$\left(\begin{matrix} x_1 &y_1\\-y_1&x_1 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} x_2 &y_2\\-y_2&x_2\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix} x_1x_2-y_1y_2 &x_1y_2+x_2y_1\\-x_1y_2-x_2y_1&~x_1x_2-y_1y_2  \end{matrix}\right)\in M$$

Comment: Habit.  Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the multiplication and got that it worked out fine. There must be a mistake you're making with the matrix multiplication.

Just remember that no matter what $a_{12}$ is, $a_{21}$ should be its negative.